# What is wrong with this RedirectMatch expression?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to use this RedirectMatch:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*.p0) /(.*.p1)
```

to replace a page parameter in the url.
old url: `http://www.example.com/some-list-c1-p0`
new url: `http://www.example.com/some-list-c1-p1`

What is wrong with it?

Or can I make a rule that redirects 301 the following kind of urls?

old url: `http://www.example.com/some-list-c1-p0.html`
new url: `http://www.example.com/some-list-c1-p1`

I'm using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*.p0)\.html /$1
```

But I can't get that 'p1' instead of 'p0'

Answer (score 1):

Your replacement side does not contain any references to the matches. [The Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) suggest examples like this:

```
RedirectMatch "(.*)\.gif$" "http://other.example.com$1.jpg"
```

using `$1`, `$2`, etc. to refer to the captured matches, so try

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*.)p0 /$1p1
```

and see if that works better.

Comment: It worked on the url, but added the parameters at the end. Like this
http://www.example.com/some-list-c1-p1?id=1&page=0

Comment: So how can I remove this from the end of the url (?id=1&page=0)?

Comment: @nickRO87: it _might_ (untested) work by having the replacement URL end in `?`, otherwise, you probably need to use [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), which has a `QSA` flag to control whether query parameters are stripped or not.

Comment: Not working..
How do I write the cond in mod_rewrite?

I'm trying:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=0 [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*.)$p0 /$1p1 [R=301,QSA]
</IfModule> 

Not working

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround with the 2nd part of my question

This works:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*.)p0\.html /$1p1
```